# Php Variable declaration error - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, variables, syntax, declaration

I am very new to php. I have a simple website that loops through a mysql database and draws polygons for every row. It also assigns a custom attribute (name) to every polygon that the user can see when he clicks the polygon.

When a user clicks the polygon, he should see the value of variable "bname"

The code works perfectly when I assign bname to a coordinate:

```
var bname = ('.$row[coord1].');
```

The code fails when I assign bname to another column that is a string:

```
var bname = ('.$row[name].');
```

All data in the database is text format, I suspect that maybe I am using the wrong syntax to return a string value from the database? I need to assign bname to the name column in the database..

This is the full code:

```
$findmap= 'SELECT * FROM build2';

if(!$result = $con->query($findmap)){
die('There was an error running the query 
    [' . $con->error . ']');
} else {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  echo '        
        var polypath = [new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[coord1].'),
                new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[coord2].'),
                new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[coord3].'),
                new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[coord4].'),
                new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[coord5].'),
                new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[coord6].'),
                new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[coord1].')
                ];


        var bname = ('.$row[name].');

        var dxbmap = new google.maps.Polygon({
        custom: bname,
        path:polypath,
        strokeColor:"#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity:0.8,
        strokeWeight:1,
        fillColor:"#0000FF",
        fillOpacity:0.1

        });

        dxbmap.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(dxbmap, "click", function() {
        alert(this.custom);

    });

';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Try like :-  `var bname = ("$row['name']"); Or
var bname = ($row['name']);` and check.

Comment: If it is a string I think it needs to be in quotes. Check the developer console, what is the error being thrown?

Comment: If I understand your question, then you need to add <script> tag before "var polypath" as well close it after "});" and for PHP db variable you should use like $row["coord2"] instead of $row[coord2]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, unfortunately however the adjustments did not resolve the problem with the variable.    @anant -both adjustments didn't work, it only works with the "." as in the code I shared above.

Comment: @ghanshyam -Thanks but It didnt work, however please note that when I fetch the "coord" column it works fine. the issue is only when fetching the "name" column from the DB.

Comment: @chris85 -I've tried so many variations of quotations/declarations however with no luck so far. The error log states the following:- `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'name' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home3/yahya/public_html/mapv2.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your console in the browser for JS errors which I think is what you are encountering. Try this

```
$findmap= 'SELECT * FROM build2';

if(!$result = $con->query($findmap)){
die('There was an error running the query 
    [' . $con->error . ']');
} else {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  echo '        
        var polypath = [new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[coord1].'),
                new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[coord2].'),
                new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[coord3].'),
                new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[coord4].'),
                new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[coord5].'),
                new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[coord6].'),
                new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[coord1].')
                ];


        var bname = \''.$row[name].'\';

        var dxbmap = new google.maps.Polygon({
        custom: bname,
        path:polypath,
        strokeColor:"#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity:0.8,
        strokeWeight:1,
        fillColor:"#0000FF",
        fillOpacity:0.1

        });

        dxbmap.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(dxbmap, "click", function() {
        alert(this.custom);

    });

';
}
}
?>
```

With your current code your console log I think would be displaying something like

> Uncaught ReferenceError:

The parenthesis don't encapsulate a string, is that what you were trying to do with those?